# solving mpi oversubscribtion using other methods than mpi variables in c

Tags: c, mpi

**version 2 of my question, I hope more clear this time**

is there any method to avoid mpi oversubscription other than mpi global/local variables?

oversubscription comes with severe degradation of performance, in my case form 30 minutes in one node without mpi, to more than 3 hours in 2 nodes

this is because more than one processes are trying to access in the same time, the same node

maybe a loop which splits 300 processes in portions equal to number of nodes, or spawn a number of processes egual with number of nodes ... can avoid oversubscription

any hint/example/link would be good

thank you

Comment: intrinsics are implemented by the compiler (e.g. `icc`). You do not have to use Intel MPI in order to use Intel compilers.

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet yes, I written as shout as I could, sometimes not so clear. I wanted to say that (in one hand) I use intel compiler because has all inside (intrinsics, mpi optimized libraries...) If I use gcc with openmpi, maybe they are not so well integrated as intel and running time is bigger. On the other hand , the problem with intel is they are changing variables more often as openmpi or mpich (maybe I'm wrong). So, I've tried to explain why I want to avoid variables and find a classical way.

Comment: my point was an other approach is to use Open MPI and the Intel compilers. I have a really hard time understanding what your problem is, so you might want to edit your question Keep in mind that MPI task binding is not part of the standard, and hence each MPI implementation has its own way of doing it.

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet I've cleared up everything (including my mind :-))

Comment: MPI oversubscribtion is when you ask more MPI tasks than slots. What is the problem you are trying to fix ?

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet I know you can do more than "overquestioning", you helped me 2 months ago on other mpi post. So, do you need a code? The code what I have is long and reads some data from txt files, it takes me a bit to clean it up. Or is my post still not clear enough, now? anyway, thank you for supporting me

Comment: I do not understand your problem statement yet.

Comment: oversubscription is when **you** decide to start more MPI tasks than available slots. It is trivial to avoid it : do not start more MPI tasks than available slots. If a naive implementation of your algorithm would require more MPI tasks than available slots, then change your implementation. A typical approach is to use a pool of workers (1 worker = 1 MPI task running on a dedicated slot). An example is at http://etutorials.org/Linux+systems/cluster+computing+with+linux/Part+II+Parallel+Programming/Chapter+8+Parallel+Programming+with+MPI/8.2+Manager+Worker+Example/

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet, this is my first "date" with oversubscription, so I agree it is naive. thank you for putting me on the right track again, we can consider this post solved !